# Intersection point across two diagrams with manipulate: Problems with Coordinates

Tags: equation-solving, manipulate, column

I am trying to highlight the intersection point (point, dashed lines) in the bottom diagram and the the corresponding point in the top diagram.  Unfortunately, I am creating lots of error messages in the second output - coordinates from Solve and NSolve.

```
ClearAll[f, fp, g, x, a, b, m, intersect1, xintersect, xintersect, yintersect1, h1line, v1line, intersect2]
f[a_, x_] := a*Log[x];
fp[a_, x_] := a/x;
g[b_, m_, x_] := b + m*x;

(*Intersection Point in bottom diagram *)
intersect1[a_, b_, m_] := {x, fp[a, x]} /. 
  NSolve[fp[a, x] == g[b, m, x], x]
xintersect[a_, b_, m_] := Part[intersect[a, b, m], 1]
yintersect1[a_, b_, m_] := Part[intersect[a, b, m], 2]

(*Dashed lines for intersection point in bottom diagram *)
h1line[a_, b_, m_] := 
 Line[{{0, yintersect1[a, b, m]}, {xintersect[a, b, m], 
    yintersect1[a, b, m]}}]
v1line[a_, b_, m_] := 
 Line[{{xintersect[a, b, m], 0}, {xintersect[a, b, m], 
    yintersect1[a, b, m]}}]

(*Point in top diagram with dashed lines*)
yintersect2[a_, b_, m_] := f[a, xintersect[a, b, m]]
intersect2[a_, b_, m_] := {xintersect[a, b, m], yintersect[a, b, m]}

h2line[a_, b_, m_] := 
 Line[{{0, yintersect2[a, b, m]}, {xintersect[a, b, m], 
    yintersect2[a, b, m]}}]
v2line[a_, b_, m_] := 
 Line[{{xintersect[a, b, m], 0}, {xintersect[a, b, m], 
    yintersect2[a, b, m]}}]

(* Working Output*)
Manipulate[
 Column[{Plot[f[a, x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {25, 1600}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}], 
   Plot[{fp[a, x], g[b, m, x]}, {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {25, 600}, 
    Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize@Large, Point@intersect1[a, b, m]}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "f'(x), g(x)"}]}],
 {{a, 400}, 1, 1500}, {{b, 50}, 0, 250}, {{m, 10}, 0, 50}]

(* Error Messages *)
Manipulate[
 Column[{Plot[f[a, x], {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {25, 1600}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, 
    Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize@Large, Point@intersect2[a, b, m]}], 
   Plot[{fp[a, x], g[b, m, x]}, {x, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> {25, 600}, 
    Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize@Large, Point@intersect1[a, b, m]
      , Dashed, h1line[a, b, m], v1line[a, b, m]}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "f'(x), g(x)"}]}],
 {{a, 400}, 1, 1500}, {{b, 50}, 0, 250}, {{m, 10}, 0, 50}]
```

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[a_, x_] := a*Log[x];
fp[a_, x_] := a/x;
g[b_, m_, x_] := b + m*x;
```

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) for `intersect1` once rather than for each set of parameters.

```
(*Intersection Point in bottom diagram*)

intersect1[a_, b_, m_] = {x, fp[a, x]} /.
  Assuming[Thread[{a, b, m} > 0],
    Solve[{fp[a, x] == g[b, m, x], a > 0, b > 0, m > 0, x > 0}, x] // 
     Simplify][[1]]

(* {(-b + Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a m])/(2 m), (2 a m)/(-b + Sqrt[b^2 + 4 a m])} *)
```

The RHS of the next two lines should have `intersect1[a, b, m]` rather than `intersect[a, b, m]`

```
xintersect[a_, b_, m_] = Part[intersect1[a, b, m], 1];
yintersect1[a_, b_, m_] = Part[intersect1[a, b, m], 2];

(*Dashed lines for intersection point in bottom diagram*)

h1line[a_, b_, m_] := 
 Line[{{0, yintersect1[a, b, m]}, {xintersect[a, b, m], yintersect1[a, b, m]}}]
v1line[a_, b_, m_] := 
 Line[{{xintersect[a, b, m], 0}, {xintersect[a, b, m], yintersect1[a, b, m]}}]

(*Point in top diagram with dashed lines*)

yintersect2[a_, b_, m_] := f[a, xintersect[a, b, m]]
```

RHS of next line should have `yintersect2[a, b, m]` rather than `yintersect[a, b, m]`

```
intersect2[a_, b_, m_] := {xintersect[a, b, m], yintersect2[a, b, m]}

h2line[a_, b_, m_] := 
 Line[{{0, yintersect2[a, b, m]}, {xintersect[a, b, m], yintersect2[a, b, m]}}]
v2line[a_, b_, m_] := 
 Line[{{xintersect[a, b, m], 0}, {xintersect[a, b, m], yintersect2[a, b, m]}}]

Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[f[a, x], {x, 0, 30},
    PlotRange -> {25, 1600},
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"},
    Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize@Large,
      Point@intersect2[a, b, m]},
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   Plot[{fp[a, x], g[b, m, x]}, {x, 0, 30},
    PlotRange -> {25, 600},
    Epilog -> {
      Blue, PointSize@Large, Point@intersect1[a, b, m],
      Dashed, h1line[a, b, m], v1line[a, b, m]}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x", "f'(x), g(x)"},
    ImageSize -> Medium]}],
 {{a, 400}, 1, 1500, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{b, 50}, 1, 250, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{m, 10}, 0.5, 50, 0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Trying to adopt the solution to the application below but it is running without a solution.

Comment: Clear["Global`*"]
y[a_, k_, l_, d_] := a*k^d*l^(1 - d);
mpl[a_, k_, l_, d_] := (1 - d)*a*k^d*l^(-d)
lsupply[b_, m_, l_] := b + m*l

Comment: intersectlabor[a_, k_, l_, d_, b_, m_] = {l, mpl[a, k, l, d]} /. 
  Assuming[Thread[{a, b, m, d, k} > 0], 
    Solve[{mpl[a, k, l, d] == lsupply[b, m, l], a > 0, b > 0, m > 0, 
       l > 0, k > 0, d > 0}, l] // Simplify][[1]]
xintersectlabor[a_, k_, l_, d_, b_, m_] := 
 Part[intersectlabor[a, k, l, d, b, m], 1]
yintersectlabor[a_, k_, l_, d_, b_, m_] := 
 Part[intersectlabor[a, k, l, d, b, m], 2]

Comment: Manipulate[
 Plot[{mpl[a, k, l, d], lsupply[b, m, l]}, {l, 0, 100}, 
  PlotRange -> {25, 1000}, AxesLabel -> {"L", "MPL, w"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Black, 
  Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize@Large, 
    Point@intersectlabor[a, k, l, d, b, m]}], {{a, 80, "A"}, 1, 
  100}, {{k, 350, "K"}, 200, 1000}, {{d, 1/3}, 10^-2, 1}, {{b, 4}, 0, 
  200}, {{m, 5}, 0, 10}]

Comment: Don't ask new questions in comments. The equations given in the comments cannot be handled by `Solve`. You probably need to use numeric techniques.

Comment: I posted a new question. Thanks!